# How Would I Read From An External File

Tags: c++

Basically, I need a basic .txt -- maybe a .csv -- file that is going to be read by the program and use a number located in the file.
I would want the file to look like this:

oranges: 1.50

apples: 2.10

pears: 4.70

I would then want the program to read 1.50 from the first line and assign that to the variable orangeCost. I would then want the second part to read the second line and assign 2.10 to the variable apples, etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int garden();

    //Lawn
    int lawnLength;         
    int lawnWidth;
    int lawnTime = 20;
    float lawnCost = 15.50;

    cout << "Length of lawn required: "; // Asks for the length
    cin >> lawnLength; // Writes to variable
    cout << "Width of lawn required: "; // Asks for the width
    cin >> lawnWidth; // Writes to variable
    int lawnArea = (lawnLength * lawnWidth); //Calculates the total area
    cout << endl << "Area of lawn required is " << lawnArea << " square meters"; //Prints the total area
    cout << endl << "This will cost a total of " << (lawnArea * lawnCost) << " pounds"; //Prints the total cost
    cout << endl << "This will take a total of " << (lawnArea * lawnTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl; //Prints total time

    //Concrete Patio
    int concreteLength;         
    int concreteWidth;
    int concreteTime = 20;
    float concreteCost = 20.99;

    cout << "Length of concrete required: "; // Asks for the length
    cin >> concreteLength; // Writes to variable
    cout << "Width of concrete required: "; // Asks for the width
    cin >> concreteWidth; // Writes to variable
    int concreteArea = (concreteLength * concreteWidth); //Calculates the total area
    cout << endl << "Area of concrete required is " << concreteArea << " square meters"; //Prints the total area
    cout << endl << "This will cost a total of " << (concreteArea * concreteCost) << " pounds"; //Prints the total cost
    cout << endl << "This will take a total of " << (concreteArea * concreteTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl; //Prints total time

    //Wooden Deck
    int woodenDeckLength;           
    int woodenDeckWidth;
    int woodenDeckTime = 30;
    float woodenDeckCost = 15.75;

    cout << "Length of wooden deck required: "; // Asks for the length
    cin >> woodenDeckLength; // Writes to variable
    cout << "Width of wooden deck required: "; // Asks for the width
    cin >> woodenDeckWidth; // Writes to variable
    int woodenDeckArea = (woodenDeckLength * woodenDeckWidth); //Calculates the total area
    cout << endl << "Area of wooden deck required is " << woodenDeckArea << " square meters"; //Prints the total area
    cout << endl << "This will cost a total of " << (woodenDeckArea * woodenDeckCost) << " pounds"; //Prints the total cost
    cout << endl << "This will take a total of " << (woodenDeckArea * woodenDeckTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl; //Prints total time

    //Rectangular Pond
    int rectangularPondLength;          
    int rectangularPondWidth;
    int rectangularPondTime = 45;   
    float rectangularPondCost = 25.00;

    cout << "Length of rectangular pond required: "; // Asks for the length
    cin >> rectangularPondLength; // Writes to variable
    cout << "Width of rectangular pond required: "; // Asks for the width
    cin >> rectangularPondWidth; // Writes to variable
    int rectangularPondArea = (rectangularPondLength * rectangularPondWidth); //Calculates the total area
    cout << endl << "Area of rectangular pond required is " << rectangularPondArea << " square meters"; //Prints the total area
    cout << endl << "This will cost a total of " << (rectangularPondArea * rectangularPondCost) << " pounds"; //Prints the total cost
    cout << endl << "This will take a total of " << (rectangularPondArea * rectangularPondTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl; //Prints total time

    //Water Features
    int waterFeatures;          
    int waterFeaturesTime = 60; 
    float waterFeaturesCost = 150.00;

    cout << "Number of water features required: "; // Asks for the amount of water features needed
    cin >> waterFeatures; // Writes to variable
    cout << endl << "Number of water feature(s) required is " << waterFeatures << " water feature(s)"; //Prints the total area
    cout << endl << "This will cost a total of " << (waterFeatures * waterFeaturesCost) << " pounds"; //Prints the total cost
    cout << endl << "This will take a total of " << (waterFeatures * waterFeaturesTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl; //Prints total time

    //Garden Lights
    int gardenLights;           
    int gardenLightsTime = 10;  
    float gardenLightsCosts = 5.00;

    cout << "Number of garden lights required: "; // Asks for the amount of water features needed
    cin >> gardenLights; // Writes to variable
    cout << endl << "Number of garden light(s) required is " << gardenLights << " garden light(s)"; //Prints the total area
    cout << endl << "This will cost a total of " << (gardenLights * gardenLightsCosts) << " pounds"; //Prints the total cost
    cout << endl << "This will take a total of " << (gardenLights* gardenLightsTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl; //Prints total time

    //Quotation
    string quotation;

    cout << "Do you want to save a quotation? " << endl; //Asks if they want to save a quotation
    cin >> quotation; //Saves if they want to save a quotation or not

    if (quotation == "yes")
    {
        std::string nameOfFile;
        cout << "What would you like to save the quotation as? (Maybe using your last name) " << endl;
        cin >> nameOfFile;

        ofstream outfile(nameOfFile + ".txt"); // Opens file in write mode

        //Lawn
        outfile << "The total lawn area is " << lawnArea << " square meters" << endl; // Writes users data into the file 
        outfile << "The total cost for the lawn is £" << (lawnArea * lawnCost) << endl; // Writes users data into the file 
        outfile << "The total time for the lawn is " << (lawnArea * lawnTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl; // Writes users data into the file 
        //Concrete Patio
        outfile << "The total concrete patio area is " << concreteArea << " square meters" << endl; 
        outfile << "The total cost for the concrete patio is £" << (concreteArea * concreteCost) << endl;
        outfile << "The total time for the concrete patio is " << (concreteArea * concreteTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl;
        //Wooden Deck
        outfile << "The total wooden deck area is " << woodenDeckArea << " square meters" << endl;
        outfile << "The total cost for the wooden deck is £" << (woodenDeckArea * woodenDeckCost) << endl;
        outfile << "The total time for the wooden deck is " << (woodenDeckArea * woodenDeckTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl;
        //Rectangular Pond
        outfile << "The total rectangular pond area is " << rectangularPondArea << " square meters" << endl;
        outfile << "The total cost for the wooden deck is £" << (rectangularPondArea * rectangularPondCost) << endl;
        outfile << "The total time for the wooden deck is " << (rectangularPondArea * rectangularPondTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl;
        //Water Features
        outfile << "The total number of water feature(s) needed are " << waterFeatures << endl;
        outfile << "The total cost for the water feature(s) is £" << (waterFeatures * waterFeaturesCost) << endl;
        outfile << "The total time for the water feature(s) is " << (waterFeatures * waterFeaturesTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl;
        //Garden Lights
        outfile << "The total number of garden light(s) needed are " << gardenLights << endl;
        outfile << "The total cost for the garden light(s) is £" << (gardenLights * gardenLightsCosts) << endl;
        outfile << "The total time for the garden light(s) is " << (waterFeatures * waterFeaturesTime) << " minutes" << endl << endl;       
        //CLOSE FILE
        outfile.close(); // Close's the file.
        cout << "Quotation saved." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Quotation not saved." << endl;
    }


    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: Did you paste the correct code? The code you've posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with apples and oranges.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for "C++ read from file parse".  We don't need duplication around here.

Comment: I did post the correct code, but I was just trying to think of something off the top of my head, it should be the same principles

Comment: I had already seen taht post @DanWatkins but I wasnt sure how to get it to read from differnet lines and a certain part of the line

Comment: No, I was not sure what I needed to do.

Comment: Then there's no reason to post irrelevant code. At least post what you have *tried*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it:

Create a class `fruit` with private variables `name` and `cost`.

Then create a constructor that takes a string (a line from the input file). Extract everything up to ':' into `name` and the value that follows into `cost`.

Your function that read file needs to do something like this:

- declare an array of fruit
- loop:
- - get a line from file into a variable
- - call the fruit class with this variable, and add the created object into an array

When you reach the end of the file, you have an array of fruits that contains all the data from the file.

to learn about classes, check: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm

to learn about reading from files, check: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Is there a sample code that I can see? I dont quite understand how to make this class and private variables thank you

Comment: Fore creating a class, google "how to create a class in c++ example", and you will see several tutorials, for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm

Comment: Do you have any further questions? Please let me know, and I will elaborate on my answer. If not, please mark my answer.